# How to stop Ubuntu from changing numlock state on boot?

Tags: boot, 18.04, keyboard, login-screen, numlock

There is no problem in other OS. Default expected behavior for standart PC - is that you:

- Set up <kbd>NumLock</kbd> initial status in the bios
- It remains same in bootloader
- It remains same at login screen
- It remains same in desktop session, until you **intentionally** change it.

So here seems to be a problem, in some "malicious" code, that forcefully disables it, during boot. Question is: **What exactly disables it?** What binary? Or what source file? Can I remove it, at least locally, on my machine, in order to stop Ubuntu from changing <kbd>NumLock</kbd> state at boot?

Or maybe that's a tweak, like `Troubleshooting features` > `[V] Force disable num lock at boot`, that was occasionally enabled by default?

I've concluded some searches, what I've found is that:

- [Official information](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NumLock#Enable_Numlock_on_Login) is outdated. There is no such menu in Ubuntu Settings as per 18.04 LTS.
- A couple of threads, [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/773804/ubuntu-16-04-turn-numlock-on-and-disable-numlock-key-permanently/774283) and [there](https://superuser.com/questions/109454/why-is-num-lock-disabled-by-default-in-ubuntu), are also not answering where does the illness seats.
- Installing and using `numlockx` is a stub. Why do we need disable (initially enabled) <kbd>NumLock</kbd>, and then use additional software to re-enable it? Such an advice really sounds like somthing "conceptually wrong".

Can you help to find out, where is the disease source, and how to fight it?

Comment: AFAIK it's a hardware issue. I have 2 PCs both running 18.04 LTS. One has a usb keyboard (Num Lock works on boot) the other is a PS2 keyboard (Num Lock doesn't persist on boot). There is no malicious code issue. You are barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: @Graham USB keyboard, NumLock does not persists in Ubuntu. But does in another OS. So its definetely a software issue.

Comment: Nope, can't accept that. The PC where the USB keyboard is working was previously the PC with the PS2 keyboard and didn't work. Same machine, same OS different hardware. This is not a software issue.

Comment: @24601 I am experiencing under 20.04 the same problem as xakepp35. In the BIOS I did set Num Lock = On, but during boot it turns off! Maybe this behaviour is because I am using a mini-pc, so Ubuntu is thinking I am using a laptop and laptops don't have a numeric keypad? Other OS from USB-stick does behave as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### For Ubuntu Gnome 18.04+

When you are at the login screen the user ID active is `gdm` (Gnome Desktop Manager). To change that profile login with your own user ID and use:

```bash
sudo -i
xhost +SI:localuser:gdm
su gdm -s /bin/bash
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.keyboard numlock-state 'on'
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad tap-to-click true
```

For a plethora of even more options:

- [How to enable numlock at boot time for login screen?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/155679/how-to-enable-numlock-at-boot-time-for-login-screen)

---

### For Ubuntu Unity 16.04+

Install the the program `numlockx`:

```bash
$ sudo apt update && sudo apt install numlockx

$ numlockx -h
NumLockX 1.2
(C) 2000-2001 Lubos Lunak <l.lunak@kde.org>
(C) 2001      Oswald Buddenhagen <ossi@kde.org>

Usage: numlockx [on|off|toggle|status]
on     - turns NumLock on in X ( default )
off    - turns NumLock off in X
toggle - toggles the NumLock on and off in X
status - gets the NumLock status
```

Next step is to get it running during login screen:

```bash
$ locate 50-unity-greeter.conf
/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-unity-greeter.conf

$ sudo -H gedit /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-unity-greeter.conf
```

#### At bottom of file add:

```bash
greeter-setup-script=/usr/bin/numlockx on
```

Save file and login again.

---

### Catchall when everything fails

Install `numlockx` as show above. Then

```bash
$ sudo -H gedit /etc/rc.local
```

#### At bottom of file add:

```bash
/usr/bin/numlockx on
```

Save file and reboot.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your input. I've tried it but it didn't work. It does not even toggles state on a running machine..

Comment: @xakepp35 Turned out many options in the link don't work. I've updated answer with catchall at bottom that worked for me just now.

Comment: 19.10 responds `No such key “numlock-state”`

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu 20:

All the same reasoning applies but the specific key/values have changed

```
org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.keyboard remember-numlock-state true
org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.keyboard numlock-state false
```

Comment: does not work under Hyper-V

Comment: Does not work 21.10

Answer (score 0):

I actually wanted to disable numlock but this may well also force the enable situation as well.

I installed `numlockx` by running:

```
sudo apt install numlockx
```

and set the default status in `/etc/default/numlockx`:

```
# Configuration file for numlockx

# State of numlog on start of X session
# Accepts following options:
#  auto - turns numlock on unless ran on laptop
#  on - turns numlock on
#  off - turns numlock off
#  keep - does not change numlock state
#  toggle - toggles numlock state
NUMLOCK=off
```

A sledgehammer approach but worked.