# Make numerical keyboard (num lock) active by default on Ubuntu Server

Tags: login, password, startup, numlock

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.3 Server (i.e. no graphical interface, only terminal) as a virtual machine of VirtualBox. How can I make the numerical keyboard active by default directly after Ubuntu is started up, when I type my login and password (too dreary activate it manually every time)?

Comment: Does this help: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1184674/how-to-stop-ubuntu-from-changing-numlock-state-on-boot/1184884#1184884

Comment: As far as I understand, numlockx works only when graphical interface is available. I have Server version of Ubuntu - no graphical interface. Therefore, your link is useless to me.

Comment: you can install numlock , see also # xset --help  [options[ ----- i suggest too seeing # man kbd_mode

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu 20.04:

```
sudo gsettings set com.canonical.unity.settings-daemon.peripherals.keyboard numlock-state 'on'
```

Answer (score 0):

Please open a terminal window, then run

```
sudo -i && xhost +SI:localuser:gdm
su gdm -s /bin/bash
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.keyboard numlock-state 'on'
```

then advise, after a reboot of the virtual machine, if NumLock is now on.

Comment: 19.10 responds `No such key “numlock-state”`